# Python download multiple files in a loop

Tags: python, linux, urllib2

I have problems with my code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.1

import urllib.request;

# Disguise as a Mozila browser on a Windows OS
userAgent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT)';

URL = "www.example.com/img";
req = urllib.request.Request(URL, headers={'User-Agent' : userAgent});

# Counter for the filename.
i = 0;

while True:
    fname =  str(i).zfill(3) + '.png';
    req.full_url = URL + fname;

    f = open(fname, 'wb');

    try:
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(req);
    except:
        break;
    else:
        f.write(response.read());
        i+=1;
        response.close();
    finally:
        f.close();
```

The problem seems to come when I create the urllib.request.Request object (called req). I create it with a non-existing url but later I change the url to what it should be. I'm doing this so that I can use the same urllib.request.Request object and not have to create new ones on each iteration. There is probably a mechanism for doing exactly that in python but I'm not sure what it is.

**EDIT**
Error message is:

```
>>> response = urllib.request.urlopen(req);
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.1/urllib/request.py", line 121, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.1/urllib/request.py", line 356, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.1/urllib/request.py", line 468, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.1/urllib/request.py", line 394, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.1/urllib/request.py", line 328, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.1/urllib/request.py", line 476, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

**EDIT 2**: My solution is the following. Probably should have done this at the start as I knew it would work:

```
import urllib.request;

# Disguise as a Mozila browser on a Windows OS
userAgent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT)';

# Counter for the filename.
i = 0;

while True:
    fname =  str(i).zfill(3) + '.png';
    URL = "www.example.com/img" + fname;

    f = open(fname, 'wb');

    try:
        req = urllib.request.Request(URL, headers={'User-Agent' : userAgent});
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(req);
    except:
        break;
    else:
        f.write(response.read());
        i+=1;
        response.close();
    finally:
        f.close();
```

Comment: And what is the error message ? Also, python don't need the semi-colon to end a line.

Comment: I've added the error message. I know that I don't need semicolons but I prefer to add them. The url and file exist. The only problem is that I'm creating the req object with an invalid url and then before I use req I correct the url.  That seems to be causing the error.

Comment: It is. The url is valid. It's how it's set that's causing the problem. I can also access the url, wget it and download it with Python if I don't have a loop and so I set the url in req object correctly when I create it.

Comment: why would anyone prefer to add spurious semicolons everywhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`urllib2` is fine for small scripts that only need to do one or two network interactions, but if you are doing a lot more work, you will likely find that either [`urllib3`](http://code.google.com/p/urllib3/), or [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/v0.10.7/index.html) (which not coincidentally is built on the former), may suit your needs better.    Your particular example might look like:

```
from itertools import count
import requests

HEADERS = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT)'}
URL = "http://www.example.com/img%03d.png"

# with a session, we get keep alive
session = requests.session()

for n in count():
    full_url = URL % n
    ignored, filename = URL.rsplit('/', 1)

    with file(filename, 'wb') as outfile:
        response = session.get(full_url, headers=HEADERS)
        if not response.ok:
            break
        outfile.write(response.content)
```

Edit:  If you can use regular HTTP authentication (for which the `403 Forbidden` response strongly suggests), then you can add that to a `requests.get` with the `auth` parameter, as in:

```
response = session.get(full_url, headers=HEADERS, auth=('username','password))
```

Comment: I like this answer, instead of just fixing a bug for OP you actually demonstrate a much better way of doing it, thus solving his and maybe other people problems.

Comment: It know it is a long time since the original post, but the filename should read `ignored, filename = full_url.rsplit('/', 1)` instead of `ignored, filename = URL.rsplit('/', 1)`. Otherwise the filename will be `img%03d.png`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the custom user agent with every request, you can subclass `FancyURLopener`.

Here's an example: http://wolfprojects.altervista.org/changeua.php

Answer (score -2):

Don't break when you receive an exception. Change

```
except:
    break
```

to

```
except:
    #Probably should log some debug information here.
    pass
```

This will skip all problematic request, so that one doesn't bring down the whole process.

Comment: That will change the logic considerably.  He most likely does not wish to loop forever.

Comment: I'm using the exception as a way to terminate the loop. A pass will result in an infinite loop. I don't know how many files there are so I'm downloading till I run into an exception.

Comment: Won't prevent the server from throttling though.

Comment: I don't think that would be a problem. I'm trying to resolve this problem first.